# Send drive folder list to listbox HTML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a script that is pulling all the folders in my drive. I want to push this data into a listbox that has been created in HTML (UiApp is deprecated)

The code I have is (note that the sheet.appendRow line doesn't work and if you know why and feel like explaining that would be awesome!!)

```
function updateFoldersListbox(FoldersListBox) {

var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
var driveFolders = rootFolder.getFolders();

  while (driveFolders.hasNext()) {
  var addMonitoredFolder = driveFolders.next();
  Logger.log(addMonitoredFolder);
  //sheet.appendRow(addMonitoredFolder);
}
```

The output of the logs is:

```
[15-09-26 01:38:46:603 BST] Test Folder
[15-09-26 01:38:46:605 BST] Untitled folder
[15-09-26 01:38:46:606 BST] Notes
```

Now to push that to a listbox and add test folder, untitled folder and notes as an option:

```
  <select name="sometext" size="5">
    <option>option1</option>
  </select>
```

How is that done?

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code in a script file:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Dialog').addItem('Open', 'openDialog').addToUi();
};

function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a Google Drive Folder:');
};

function updateFoldersListbox() {  
  var rootFolder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  var driveFolders = rootFolder.getFolders();
  var listnames = new Array();
  while (driveFolders.hasNext()) {
    var addMonitoredFolder = driveFolders.next().getName();
    listnames.push([addMonitoredFolder]);
    //Logger.log(addMonitoredFolder);
    //sheet.appendRow(addMonitoredFolder);
  }
  return listnames;
};
```

And put the following code in a HTML file 'Index.html':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

  <select id="menu">  </select>

  <script
  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
  // The code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
  $(function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showThings)
    .updateFoldersListbox();
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showMenu)
    .updateFoldersListbox();
    });

  function showThings(things) {
    var list = $('#things');
    list.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {
      list.append('<li>' + things[i] + '</li>');
    }
  }

  function showMenu(menuItems) {
    var list = $('#menu');
    list.find('option').remove();  // remove existing contents

    for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
      list.append('<option>' + menuItems[i] + '</option>');
    }
  }

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, run the function 'openDialog' from the script editor.
Or refresh your spreadsheet and run the function from the custom menu 'Dialog' > 'Open'.